# Change Alpha on Rollover; Not Changing Back on Mouse Out?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have a Tile class, with a sprite variable that holds the graphic for the tile. On mouse over, I ColorTransform the graphic. Seems to work fine. On mouse out, I try to change it back. Nada. And in fact, rolling over the same tile twice will increase the alpha until eventually it fades totally. Not sure how to fix it. Here's my code.

In the Tile class:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, thisMouseOver);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, thisMouseOut );

public function thisMouseOver( e:Event ):void {
    tileGraphic.bitmapData = setAlpha(tileGraphic.bitmapData);
}

public function thisMouseOut( e:Event ):void {
    tileGraphic.bitmapData = resetAlpha(tileGraphic.bitmapData);
}

private function setAlpha( bmd:BitmapData ):BitmapData {
    var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height );
    var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    ct.alphaMultiplier = .65;
    bmd.colorTransform( rec, ct );
    return bmd;
} //end function setAlpha

private function resetAlpha( bmd:BitmapData ):BitmapData {
    var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height );
    var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    ct.alphaMultiplier = 1;
    bmd.colorTransform( rec, ct );
    return bmd;
} //end function resetAlpha
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried 1.54 as alphaMultiplier for reset ?

Comment: I tried it just to be sure, and nothing was different. If I am correct, I believe `alphaMultiplier` only works on a scale of 0 to 1. If you set it any higher than 1, it reverts to 1.

Comment: Hm.... Let me try this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the resetAlpha with

```
    private function resetAlpha( bmd:BitmapData ):BitmapData {
        var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height );
        var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        ct.alphaOffset = 255
        bmd.colorTransform( rec, ct );
        return bmd;
    } //end function resetAlpha
```

Comment: I really want to minus this one, because if a base bitmap has a decent alpha gradient, this will eliminate alpha data. The correct way would be either a) preserve initial bitmap state and apply alpha transformation to a Bitmap object (or containing Sprite), or b) to employ proper multipliers. Alpha multiplier **should** work properly when it's above 1.0, but OP states it doesn't... while weird, it should be respected.

Comment: I agree, preserving the original bitmapdata would be a better way, but since I do not know why he did not initially, there might be a reason for this.

Comment: I see one valid reason to do so - if there are several bitmaps that share one bitmapdata, as if a block-elimination game with a helper to show similar objects will assign tiles to one single bitmapdata, thus this method will make all relevant bitmaps to fade out first. But, in this case I'd use two "base" bitmaps, one opaque and one semi-transparent, and one shared bitmapdata, and then call a `copyPixels()` to simultaneously change all affected bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

You should better change alpha of the container instead of playing with the `BitmapData` pixels. For example, in your case if your tile bitmap will initially have transparent pixels (fill it with 0x00ff0000 prior to drawing a thing and check if so), they will become opaque with codingbuddha's answer. So, change the listeners to the following:

```
public function thisMouseOver( e:Event ):void {
    tileGraphic.alpha=0.65;
}

public function thisMouseOut( e:Event ):void {
    tileGraphic.alpha=1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Also very helpful! I hadn't thought of anything like that.